# Can Unicode text be colored in marshmallow

Tags: android

In Marshmallow certain Unicode characters like u2666 (diamond) have a prescribed color that I can't seem to style to a different color. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How are you doing the styling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color in the Unicode standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626115/color-in-the-unicode-standard)

Comment: The question about "Color in the Unicode standard" might be a hint, but I can't find a way to specify the variant selector. @CommonsWare I'm willing to style it any way that might work. I've tried to use android:textColor, but this has no impact.

Comment: You could try a `ForegroundColorSpan`.

Comment: @CommonsWare unfortunately a ForegroundColorSpan doesn't change the appearance of that character. To make sure I was doing it right I applied the ForegroundColorSpan to my entire string, the ASCII characters in the string were styled, but not the unicode character in question.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know if this is somehow typeface-specific. If it is, you could try a different font. But, otherwise, I'm running short on ideas.