# How to change the color of a unicode character

Tags: unicode

I'm trying to get a green, cyan, purple and yellow large circle like this one: , but there aren't any codes for one. Is there any way to change the code to change the color?

Comment: Color is generally orthogonal to character. It is more a question of display device.

Comment: Why do you need to use unicode-characters? If you're displaying this as HTML, can't you just make them with containers and CSS? Or use a thing like FontAwesome, with the filled circle?

Comment: Unicode defines glyphs, which is the code points and the shape of the characters, not the color. Some new fonts and font renderers have support for color emoji but generally font size, color, boldness, slantness cannot be controlled by Unicode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color in the Unicode standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626115/color-in-the-unicode-standard)

Comment: This is a useful resource for when you can't or don't want to (or can't) touch the front-end but want some colorful characters (e.g. on a headless CMS): https://emojiterra.com/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. The color is inherent to the character -- there's a LARGE BLUE CIRCLE as well (U+1F535 - ), but no other colors are currently defined by the Unicode standard.

Comment: even the LARGE BLUE CIRCLE isn't necessarily rendered in color http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f535/index.htm

Comment:  ...

Answer (score 18):

If using HTML, you can append xFE0E to get the text version and color that using CSS:

```html
<span>&#x1f534;</span>
<span>&#x1f534;&#xfe0e;</span>
<span style="color: lime;">&#x1f534;&#xfe0e;</span>
```

Comment: I saw no mention of HTML/CSS/web in the question. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, you did not miss anything.

Comment: Worked perfect for me. This solved a problem I had with it not changing colors at all. Now I can finally change the color like I needed to.

Answer (score 13):

Unicode is huge, even has Klingon, it has more colors and even smileys nowadays...
Here you go, change the numbers to search and find what you need...

```
for i in range (10):
    ii = int('0x1f7e0',base=16)+i
    print('{:>15}'.format('[{}: {}] '.format(hex(ii),chr(ii))),end='')
    if i%7==6:
        print()
```

[image]

For cyan circle, try starting from 0x1f7df with range 1000... Also note that unicode color is best effort, so e.g. on a Klingon browser things may not display in colour...

Also, to find the codes of characters you have e.g.:

```
chars=''
for i,c in enumerate(chars):
    print('[{}: {}] '.format(hex(ord(c)),c), end='')
    if i%7==6:
        print()
```

Gives:

```
[0x1f535: ] [0x1f534: ] [0x1f7e0: ] [0x1f7e1: ] [0x1f7e2: ] [0x1f7e3: ] [0x1f7e4: ] 
[0x1f7e6: ] [0x1f7e5: ] [0x1f7e7: ] [0x1f7e8: ] [0x1f7e9: ] [0x1f7ea: ] [0x1f7eb: ] 
[0x1f6d1: ] [0x1f536: ] [0x1f537: ] [0x1f538: ] [0x1f539: ] [0x1f53a: ] [0x1f53b: ]
```

Comment: Is there a LightGrey version of these symbols please?

Answer (score 6):

In both HTML and CSS, you can append xFE0E to get the text version and color that :

In HTML:

```html
<div>&#x274c;</div>
<div style= "color: blue;">&#x274c;&#xfe0e;</div>
<div style= "color: green;">&#x274c;&#xfe0e;</div>
```

In CSS:

```css
.css-symbol:after {
  color: black;
  content: "\274C";
}

.css-symbol1:after {
  color: black;
  content: "\274C\fe0e";
}

.css-symbol2:after {
  color: blue;
  content: "\274C\fe0e";
}
```

```html
<div class="css-symbol">css:&nbsp;</div>

<div class="css-symbol1">css:&nbsp;</div>
<div class="css-symbol2">css:&nbsp;</div>
```

Mixing Both HTML and CSS:

```css
div {
  color: black;
}


.css-symbol:after {
  color: blue;
  content: "\274C\fe0e";
}
```

```html
<div>&#x274c;</div>
<div>&#x274c;&#xfe0e;</div>
<div class="css-symbol"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Unicode character for a black large circle and paint it with what you want using CSS:
⬤

```
&#11044;
```

Or this one (smaller):
●

```
&#9679;
```

This is good, for example, to show colours samples instead of using JPG, PNG, etc.

```html
<p style="color:pink;">Circle ⬤● Example</p>
<p style="color:#0000ff;">Circle ⬤● Example</p>
<p style="color:rgb(255, 255, 0);">Circle ⬤● Example</p>
```