# How can I change the color of a unicode character

Tags: unicode

I'm trying to get a blue unicode like this one: , but there aren't any codes for one. Is there any way to change the code to change the color?

I had try to search in my browser but I not found the answer if you now that unicode with blue color answer below

Comment: Unicode doesn't support well colours. You should use protocols on other layers. Note: your character is `VERY HEAVY EIGHT POINTED BLACK STAR`, but on many terminals it is shows a *white star* (one of the big "white/black" problem in Unicode. Some emoji has some support, and you can tell font (with unicode variant) if you prefer black and white or colour symbols (if available). But not much more. And inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing it in html, you can change the color of the unicode by css.

first wrap it in a span tag

```
 <span style="color: blue"></span>
```

and you can directly use style in the tag or seperate it in css file

Answer (score 0):

[Another question has been asked!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598497/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-unicode-character)

Basically, The color belongs to the character Unicode. This is the Unicode  [U+1F7D0 (128976)] [VERY HEAVY EIGHT POINTED BLACK STAR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Unicode/Geometric_Shapes_Extended). Here you can see the CIRCLE and SQUARE with different colors.

You have to use other things for rendering this .