# Why is the "purple heart" not purple in Chrome?

Tags: unicode, html-rendering

I've just noticed that there is [U+1F49C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f49c/index.htm) - PURPLE HEART.

I always thought that Unicode would abstract from color, hence I wonder why this symbol exists in the first place.

The next thing I wondered is how

```
<span style="color: red;">I &#128156; Unicode</span>    &#128156;
```

is supposed to look like. Should the heart be red or purple?

Chrome 61 (on Linux) makes the purple heart red. Hence it is black in normal text. But then I would expect the [BLUE HEART](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f499/index.htm) to look identical, which it isn't (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/4xddoas5/1/)).

What is the reason for this?

Comment: In my Chrome 61, purple heart is purple, and blue heart is blue. Nothing is red  except the text. Unicode does abstract from color, except in some cases. If it was colorless, the symbol would be named 'heart' not 'blue heart'.

Comment: In order to back you claim about problematic color, could you supply the image? Also add the operating system etc.

Comment: It all has to do with what fonts are installed. If you have a color-aware font that contains the symbol, it will always be purple. Otherwise, it will be default black, -> red.

Comment: @o11c – Installed where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color in the Unicode standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626115/color-in-the-unicode-standard)

Comment: @o11c There are color-aware fonts? 

Comment: @MartinThoma yes, see the answer by Icosie on the duplicate

Comment: Interesting. On chrome 61 for Android the purple heart is purple and the blue heart is blue.