# Jupyter: How to change color for widgets like SelectMultiple()?

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

**The challenge:**

How can you change the color for backround, font etc for [widgets.SelectMultiple()](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#SelectMultiple) and other widgets for that matter? Here's a simple setup for `widgets.SelectMultiple()`

**Snippet / Cell 1:**

```
# settings
%matplotlib inline

# imports
from ipywidgets import interactive, Layout
from IPython.display import clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# widget 1
wdg = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
    value=['Oranges'],
    #rows=10,
    description='Fruits',
    disabled=False
)

display(wdg)
```

**Widget 1:**

[image]

**What I've tried:**

I thought i was onto something with [Layout](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Simple-examples) and [style](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-style-attribute) and was hoping the following setup with `layout=Layout(width='75%', height='80px')` would let me change colors somehow as well and not only `width` and `height`:

**Snippet / Cell 2:**

```
wdg2 = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
    value=['Oranges'],
    description='Fruits',
    layout=Layout(width='75%', height='80px'),
    disabled=False
)

display(wdg2)
```

**Widget2:**

[image]

But to my huge disappointment it seems that you can't change colors in a similar way. According to the [ipywidgets docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), properties of the style attribute are specific to each widget type. You can get a list of the style attributes for a widget with the `keys` property. And `wdg2.style.keys` returns this:

```
['_model_module',
 '_model_module_version',
 '_model_name',
 '_view_count',
 '_view_module',
 '_view_module_version',
 '_view_name',
 'description_width']
```

And since there are noe color attributes there, is it impossible to change the colors for `widgets.SelectMultiple()`? For other widgets, like `Button`, you'll find an attribute `button_color` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't do that without creating your own ["custom widget"](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Custom.html).
Those attributes of `style` and `layout` objects are hard-coded in both the [server-side](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/f18700f74c9dbbb6629fb111d4cb2141b7fbde36/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_layout.py#L13) and [client-side](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/446d60864b3ef9e4615410aedf1dd59735736f52/packages/base/src/widget_layout.ts#L16) libraries of `ipywidgets`.

There is a dirty way to get a similar effect though, by mixing the `ButtonStyle` with `SelectMultiple`.

```py
# Tested on JupyterLab 0.35.3 with Python 3.6 kernel
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets.widgets import widget_serialization, trait_types

from traitlets import Unicode, Instance, CaselessStrEnum

class MySelectMultiple(widgets.SelectMultiple):
    style=trait_types.InstanceDict(widgets.ButtonStyle).tag(sync=True, **widget_serialization)

wdg2 = MySelectMultiple(
    options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
    value=['Oranges'],
    description='Fruits',
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='75%', height='80px'),
    style= {'button_color':'red'},
    disabled=False
)

wdg2
```

[image: wdg2_red]

```py
wdg2.style.button_color = 'green'
```

[image: wdg2_green]

Another dirty way is to inject a CSS rule into the notebook which affects all `select` widget.

```html
%%html
<style>
    .widget-select > select {background-color: red;}   
</style>
```

[image]

## Custom widget

The ultimate solution is to make your own [custom widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Custom.html). 
Unfortunately you need to write both server- and client side codes for it. 
For classical jupyter notebook, the client side code (JavaScript) can be put in a cell. 
But this feature may be dropped in the "next-generation" of Jupyter, i.e.  [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/overview.html), for security reasons.

Cell 1

```
%%javascript
require.undef('myselectmultiple');
define('myselectmultiple', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {
    class selectmultipleView extends widgets.SelectMultipleView {
        render () {
            super.render();
            this.mycolor_changed();
            this.model.on('change:mycolor', this.mycolor_changed, this);
        }
        mycolor_changed () {
            var mycolor = this.model.get('mycolor')
            this.el.childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = mycolor;
        }
    }
    return {
        myselectmultipleview : selectmultipleView
    };
});
```

Cell 2

```py
class MySelectMultipleC(widgets.SelectMultiple):
    _view_name = Unicode('myselectmultipleview').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('myselectmultiple').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
    mycolor = Unicode('white', help='background color').tag(sync=True)

wdg3 = MySelectMultipleC(
    options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
    value=['Oranges'],
    description='Fruits',
    mycolor = 'green',
    disabled=False
)
wdg3
```

[image]

Cell 3

```
wdg3.mycolor = 'red'
```

[image]

JupyterLab uses a completely different framework. To make the above custom widget working in the "Lab" interface, the client-side code should be translated to TypeScript, and then be compiled, built and installed on the Lab server.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! This is great! It might only be my lack of googling expertise, but this seemed impossible to find out! Would it be OK to invite you to chat for some minor follow-up questions?

Comment: I've already accepted your answer, but do you know how to change font, fontsize, and color of the selection indicator?

Comment: You can add more lines to the `render()` function in the javascript, such as `this.el.childNodes[1].style.fontSize = '12px'`.

Comment: It's better to include some CSS rules in your notebook and set the corresponding class to the `<select>` and `<option>` elements. You can find examples of CSS and select in other posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830115/select-option-font-size).

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but here is my simple solution, for the case where the color will be used to encode simple two (or a number of) states: **[use unicode!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626115/color-in-the-unicode-standard)**

sample:

[image]

code (in python 3... :) )

```
from ipywidgets import interactive, Layout
from IPython.display import clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

c_base = int("1F534",base=16)
# widget 1
options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears']
state = [False,True,True]
colored_options = ['{} {}'.format(chr(c_base+s), o) for s,o in zip(state,options)]
wdg = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=colored_options,
    description='Fruits',
    disabled=False
)

display(wdg)
```

Try searching with this code if you need more colours...:

```
for i in range (10):
    ii = int('0x1f7e0',base=16)+i
    print('{:>15}'.format('[{}: {}] '.format(hex(ii),chr(ii))),end='')
    if i%7==6:
        print()
```

[image]

Comment: I like your ingenious solution, although it doesn't really answer the original question, it inspired me to use Unicode emojis to color-code individual lines. Note that in Windows 10, you can use the `Win+.(dot)` hotkey to open an emoji menu to search for the colors ⚪⚫ :)

Answer (score 1):

`jp_proxy_widget` makes it easy to do anything you can do in HTML5/javascript in a widget.  For example here is a colorized multiple select:

[image: colorized multiple select jupyter widget]

Find it here: https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget